# Loading screen shows up after all the ajax calls have finished

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, google-chrome, loading

Hey,
i have a problem with an ajax call. i'm trying to show a loading screen which is basically a div which shows and hides while 10 ajax requests are made. it seems to work fine in firefox 3.6 but the div isn't showing up in chrome 10 and IE8. the thing is the div is showing up but its only showing up for a couple of milliseconds before it gets hidden eventhough its being opened before the ajax call. here is the function:

```
function addAllToPlaylist() {
    var title;
    var i = 1;
    var percentage = 0;
    var total = $('.tdtrackname').size();
     $('#loadingscreen').show();
     $('.tdtrackname').each(function() {
        $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'ajax/addsongtoplaylist.php?query=' + $(this).html(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#divajax').html(data);
            percentage = Math.round((i / total) * 100);
            $('#loadingmsg').html('<h3>Adding songs...please wait<br>' + i + ' / ' + total + ' (' + percentage + '%)</h3>');
        }
      });
      i++;
     });
   $('#loadingscreen').hide();
}
```

i hope you can help me out with this, i have no idea why the loading screen gets opened so late..
thanks in advance

Comment: Not an answer to your problem but wouldn't it be better to combine all your requests into one big request? I once had a similar request and managed to turn 7s loading into 2s loading. It would solve your sync/async problem too.

Answer (score 0):

You are making asynchronous requests, but dealing with the loading screen synchronously.  You need to remove this div in the success function, and you'll probably need some way of counting how many requests you still have open.

Comment: ive tried putting if (i == total) { $('#loadingscreen').hide(); } in the success function but its not working either. the problem is that the loading screen wont show up until the each() function is done...

Comment: @robs - you'd need to make i and total into global variables for that to work, as it won't exist when your success function is called.

Comment: ok, but lets say i dont want to remove the loading screen at all and i remove the hide() function. now the loading screen does show but why does it show once all the ajax calls are finished? i want it to show up before they start

Answer (score 0):

You can have it like this if you want.

```
function addAllToPlaylist() {
    var title;
    var i = 1;
    var percentage = 0;
    var total = $('.tdtrackname').size();
     $('#loadingscreen').show();

    percentage = Math.round((i / total) * 100);
            $('#loadingmsg').html('<h3>Adding songs...please wait<br>' + i + ' / ' + total + ' (' + percentage + '%)</h3>');

     $('.tdtrackname').each(function() {
        $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'ajax/addsongtoplaylist.php?query=' + $(this).html(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#divajax').html(data);
            $('#loadingscreen').hide();
        }
      });
      i++;
     });

}
```

Comment: This will hide the loading screen after the first request returns, which I don't think is what the OP wants.

Comment: exactly..i want to hide the loading screen after the each() function is finished

Answer (score 0):

You can use the always function after the ajax calls, chain them altogether, and then when all of the ajax calls are finished, close the div. This can be accomplished using a counter inside the always function specified.

Example:

```
var methodCounter = 0;

$.ajax({
  success: function(d) {
  },
  url: 'xxx',  //Where xxx is the url being hit
}).always(function() {
  methodCounter++;
  if (methodCounter == limit) { //limit is the number of times to do the ajax call before closing the dialog box
    //Hide the dialog box here
  }
});
```